# How to generate random characters between each character within a string?

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism, abstract

I have a code where I must implement an interface, and the purpose is to take a string like `mycookisred` and therein insert random characters between each from the original word. That could hinder, in this case, e.g. `meynciovoksidswrbendn`. Another example, for the sake of completeness: the `mycleverpassword` string could become `mxyschlmezvievrppeaysisvwcoorydc`.

I know my code isn't exactly right for that purpose, but can someone please help or guide me on what to do from this starting point?

```
   import java.util.Random;

  public class password implements Encryptable
{
    private String message;
    private boolean encrypted;
    private int shift;
    private Random generator;

    public password(String msg)
    {
        message = msg;
        encrypted = false;
        generator = new Random();
        shift = generator.nextInt(10) + 5;
    }
    public void encrypt()
    {
        if (!encrypted)
        {
            String masked = "";
            for ( int index = 0; index < message.length(); index++)
            masked = masked + (char)(message.charAt(index) +shift);
            message = masked;
            encrypted = true;
        }
    }
    public String decrypt()
    {
        if (!encrypted)
        {
            String unmasked = "";
            for ( int index = 0; index < message.length(); index++)
            unmasked = unmasked + (char)(message.charAt(index) - shift);
            message = unmasked;
            encrypted = false;
        }
        return message;
    }
    public boolean isEncrypted()
    {
        return encrypted;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return message;
    }

}
public class passwordTest
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      password hide = new password("my clever password");
      System.out.println(hide);

      hide.encrypt();
      System.out.println(hide);

      hide.decrypt();
      System.out.println(hide);
  }


}


public interface Encryptable
{
    public void encrypt();
    public String decrypt();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use this to randomize and normalize the String:

```
private String randomize(String s) {
    String re = "";
    int len = s.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        re += c;
        re += (char) (generator.nextInt('z' - 'a') + 'a');
    }
    re += s.charAt(len - 1);
    return re;
}

private String normalize(String s) {
    String re = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i+=2) {
        re += s.charAt(i);
    }
    return re;
}
```

And a Class should start with an upper case character. You don't need to, but for example Eclipse will cry.